# Restart app on force kill

Tags: android, background-service

I got a geolocation service. When force killed using some Task Killing apps, in the 'Manage Application' -> Running tab my App is showing as 0 Process and 1 service, and status is Restarting, but not getting restarted.

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
}
```

I started my service using

```
startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
```

Is there any way to restart the process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

`return START_STICKY`

instead.

Comment: can you please tell me the difference between force kill and force stop, because when force killed the service getting started, but when i force stopped it is not getting restarted.

Comment: A service gets force killed if the system has not enough resources left.
It is force closed if an error occurred or the user manually stopped it (and therefore it won't be restarted).

Comment: Yeah i got it. Thanks for your kind answer.