# Two times power button clicking from the home screen after clearing the cache not working

Tags: android

I am building a app which will activated after two times clicking the power button. The things are going fine when I am doing that after opening the app. But when from the home screen trying to do so. Toast is activated but the activity which should also be opened did not opened. And also when the recent apps cleared then actually nothing worked.
Here are the `broadcastreceiver` file.

```
public class CloseSystemDialogsIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public static boolean wasScreenOn = true;
static long prevTime=0;
static long currTime=0;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
    // do whatever you need to do here
    prevTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Log.d("CHECK IN RECIVER WHEN ON","CHECK IN RECIVER WHEN ON");
    wasScreenOn = false;
} else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
    // and do whatever you need to do here
    Log.d("CHECK IN RECIVER WHEN ON","CHECK IN RECIVER WHEN OFF");
    currTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    wasScreenOn = true;
}
if ((currTime - prevTime) < 1000 && (currTime - prevTime)>-1000 ) {
    if ((currTime - prevTime) < 1000 ) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "double Clicked power button",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent main=new Intent();
        main.setClassName("com.example.speechto", "com.example.speechto.MainActivity");
        main.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
       context.startActivity(main);
        Log.e("eciver ", "double Clicked power button");
        currTime = 0;
        prevTime = 0;
    }
 }
}


}
```

and the manifest file contains

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.projpb1.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.projpb1"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_new" >
    </activity>
   <receiver android:name="com.example.projpb1.CloseSystemDialogsIntentReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF"></action>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON"></action>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED"></action>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED">   
</action>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN"></action>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver> 

</application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot register SCREEN_OFF or SCREEN_ON intents for a receiver in the manifest; you must register them dynamically, by creating an intent filter and registering a receiver in your activity or service at runtime.

```
            // Add this to your Activity or Service
            // Register a receiver for the screen state change
            if (screenReceiver == null){
                IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
                filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
                screenReceiver = new CloseSystemDialogsIntentReceiver();
                registerReceiver(screenReceiver, filter);
            }
```

Comment: its working only when the activity is in the foreground.but when its going background.clicking two times power button not working.@WalkingFood

Comment: I can't be sure of this since you didn't post your Activity code, but I'm going to guess that you registered the Receiver within the Activity. When the Activity goes into the background, it's likely destroyed, which will effectively unregister (and leak, unless you're calling the unregister method in onPause or onStop) the Receiver. Activities are not meant to run in the background; for that, you'd want a Service.
For some more info, see [Android Activity Lifecycle - Stopping](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/stopping.html)

Comment: yup actually i m updating it through activity.thus when clearing the recent app the service stoped working.can you please give me idea what to do by which the service remain even after the recent apps are cleared.

Comment: You'll want to start a Service that's bound to your Application Context, then register the Receiver in that Service. From there, you can also register that Service as a Foreground Service, which will stop the system from killing it due to low memory issues. I recommend that you read [Android Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html), with [Foreground Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground) in particular.

Comment: Also, a note: this will help stop the system from killing your app, but it won't help against the user force-killing it through a TaskManager or something similar. By design, if a user kills your app that way, everything in it will stop working until the user launches the app again. See [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001184/restart-app-on-force-kill?rq=1) for a quick reference.